# Can Azure Media Services/MES generate thumbnail image from video file which stored in Azure Blob storage ?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

Recently I was trying to create Web API to upload video file to Azure Blob storage and generating thumbnail image by using ffmpeg, and upload to Azure Blob as well (different container). The whole process running well.

But I was researching on whether the Video thumbnail image can be generated itself automatically upon the video file uploaded to the specified Azure Blob container ?
Just like Azure Function -> Image Resizer. (But Azure Function Image Resizer used to resize image file to smaller image file only. Cannot process video file to generate thumbnail).

I was looking at Azure Media Services as well. May I know whether Azure Media Services are only able to process local video file to generate video thumbnail image ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are thumbnail images from uploaded videos, I would recommend [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-dotnet-migrating-console-apps/). If you want further processing of the video, then the v3 APIs in Media Services allow you to [process files in blob storage via a SAS URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-rest). You can customize the processing that you want performed on that video by designing a [custom Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/customize-encoder-presets-how-to).